# Schema.org linking multiple startdates to one event

Tags: html, microdata, schema.org

I am new to rich snippets and schema.org markup. I would like to implement it on one site but the layout is strange:

1. startDate;
2. location;
3. 3 categories of Prices;
4. multiple startDates;
5. name of the event;
6. description.

Could this fact be an obstacle for including the markup?

Moreover I am trying to find out examples how to create schema.org definition for one and the same event with multiple startDates but seems there is no spec for this. Do you know how can I do it? I have tested something but don't know if it's right...

Here is how I implemented the schema:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">
<div class="context">
<h5><time itemprop="startDate" datetime="2013-03-01">01.03.2013 Fri</time></h5>

  <form method="post" action="some action">
    <label>Location</label>
    <p itemprop="location">Gran Teatre del Liceu</p><br />
    <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://www.schema.org/Offer">
      <label itemprop="name">Ticket Categories</label>
      <p><span itemprop="price">I, &euro; 98</span><br />
      <span itemprop="price">II, &euro; 87</span><br />
      <span itemprop="price">III, &euro; 68</span><br />
      </p>
    </div>

    <ul>
      <li class="on"><a title="Order tickets" href="#"><time itemprop="startDate" datetime="2013-03-01">01.03.2013 Fri</time></a></li>
      <li><a title="Order tickets" href="#"><time itemprop="startDate" datetime="2013-03-02">02.03.2013 Sat</time></a></li>
      <li><a title="Order tickets" href="#"><time itemprop="startDate" datetime="2013-03-04">04.03.2013 Mon</time></a></li>
      <li><a title="Order tickets" href="#"><time itemprop="startDate" datetime="2013-03-05">05.03.2013 Tue</time></a></li>
    </ul><br />

    <input type="submit" value="Order tickets" class="btn" />
   </form>
</div>

   <div class="ttl">
    <h2 title="Street Scene, Opera by Kurt Weill" itemprop="name">Street Scene, Opera by Kurt Weill</h2>
   </div>
   <div class="text">
    <p itemprop="description">Midway between opera and musical</p>
   </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to have it defined for each startDate separately than having nested in the same block as

a. It gets much easier to query data (would be helpful if an event has multiple topics to be defined in the agenda). Same goes with recursive events.

b. It is impossible to provide constructs for all possible exceptions, e.g. "this meetup happens every Saturday".

c. It is very difficult or impossible to model irregular cases, e.g. if a single concert starts 20 minutes late or is cancelled, or if there has been speaker change.