# Can HTML microdata be used for multiple start dates?

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata

Using HTML microdata to markup events with single dates is straightforward. What is the proper way to achieve markup for an event with multiple start dates? Especially those with no end date.

For example:

```
<div class="event">
    <div class="details">
        <h2>Course One</h2>
        <p class="desc">
            This course is relevant for any customers </p>
        <p class="dates">Dates: 9/8, 10/10, 10/31, 12/5</p>
        <p>
            <a class="btn" href="#">Course Details</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12937815/schema-org-linking-multiple-startdates-to-one-event

Comment: And Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32274733/microdata-format-for-showing-an-event-with-multiple-date-time

Answer (score 2):

> An event happening at a certain time and location, such as a concert, lecture, or festival. Ticketing information may be added via the offers property. Repeated events may be structured as separate Event objects.

From http://schema.org/Event

You can do this in microdata, but that will result in several identical descriptions among other things.

In other words, use JSON-LD to markup several events where you change the date and/or more information if needed.